# Am tryin to generate different values for each element of a column of a numpy array using a certain range for each column but it's not abiding by it

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, random, numpy-ndarray

I need each column to generate random integers with specified range for col 1 (random.randint(1, 50) for col 2 random.randint(51, 100)...etc

```
import numpy
import random
import pandas
from random import randint
wsn = numpy.arange(1, 6)
taskn = 3

t1 = numpy.random.randint((random.randint(2, 50),random.randint(51, 100),
    random.randint(101, 150),random.randint(151, 200),random.randint(201, 250)),size=(5,5))
t2 = numpy.random.randint((random.randint(2, 50),random.randint(51, 100),
    random.randint(101, 150),random.randint(151, 200),random.randint(201, 250)),size=(5,5))
t3= numpy.random.randint((random.randint(2, 50),random.randint(51, 100),
    random.randint(101, 150),random.randint(151, 200),random.randint(201, 250)),size=(5,5))
print('\nGenerated Data:\t\n\nNumber   \t\t\t Task 1 \t\t\t Task 2 \t\t\t Task 3\n')
ni = len(t1)
for i in range(ni):
    print('\t {0}    \t   {1}   \t {2} \t {3}\n'.format(wsn[i], t1[i],t2[i],t3[i]))
print('\n\n')
```

It prints the following

```
   Generated Data:  

Number               Task 1              Task 2              Task 3

     1         [  1  13  16 121  18]     [  5  22  34  65 194]   [ 10  68  60 134 130]

     2         [  0   2 117 176  46]     [  1  15 111 116 180]   [22 41 70 24 85]

     3         [  0  12 121  19 193]     [  0   5  37 109 205]   [  5  53   5 106  15]

     4         [  0   5  97  99 235]     [  0  22 142  11 150]   [  6  79 129  64  87]

     5         [  2  46  71 101 186]     [  3  57 141  37  71]   [ 15  32   9 117  77]
```

soemtimes It even generates 0 when I didn't even specifiy 0 in the ranges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.random.randint(low, high, size=None)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) allows for `low` and `high` being arrays of length `num_intervals`.

In that case, when `size` is not specified, it will generate as many integers as there are intervals defined by the `low` and `high` bounds.

If you want to generate multiple integers per interval, you just need to specify the corresponding `size` argument, which must ends by `num_intervals`.

Here it is `size=(num_tasks, num_samples, num_intervals)`.

```py
import numpy as np

bounds = np.array([1, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250])
num_tasks = 3
num_samples = 7

bounds_low = bounds[:-1]
bounds_high = bounds[1:]
num_intervals = len(bounds_low)

arr = np.random.randint(
    bounds_low, bounds_high, size=(num_tasks, num_samples, num_intervals)
)
```

Checking the properties:

```py
assert arr.shape == (num_tasks, num_samples, num_intervals)

for itvl_idx in range(num_intervals):
    assert np.all(arr[:, :, itvl_idx] >= bounds_low[itvl_idx])
    assert np.all(arr[:, :, itvl_idx] < bounds_high[itvl_idx])
```

An example of output:

```py
array([[[ 45,  61, 100, 185, 216],
        [ 36,  78, 117, 152, 222],
        [ 18,  77, 112, 153, 221],
        [  9,  70, 123, 178, 223],
        [ 16,  84, 118, 157, 233],
        [ 42,  78, 108, 179, 240],
        [ 40,  52, 116, 152, 225]],

       [[  3,  92, 102, 151, 236],
        [ 45,  89, 138, 179, 218],
        [ 45,  73, 120, 183, 231],
        [ 35,  80, 130, 167, 212],
        [ 14,  86, 118, 195, 212],
        [ 20,  66, 117, 151, 248],
        [ 49,  94, 138, 175, 212]],

       [[ 13,  75, 116, 169, 206],
        [ 13,  75, 127, 179, 213],
        [ 29,  64, 136, 151, 213],
        [  1,  81, 140, 197, 200],
        [ 17,  77, 112, 171, 215],
        [ 18,  75, 103, 180, 209],
        [ 47,  57, 132, 194, 234]]])
```

Comment: Could you pleas explain a little what you did exactly? and I am also trying to perform this action on more than one task and column but with the same range for each column of all the tasks

Comment: Not sure which part you don't understand. I added some explanations, tell me if you still don't get it. I added the tasks dimension also.

Comment: It's understandable now with the explanation, I tried using it too and changing things so I think I got the hang of it. Much thanks!